# Child recognizing words by first and last letters; what next?

Tags: reading, children, native-language, finnish

My child, now 4 years old, seems to recognize a number of written names by their first and last letters. They also recognize some other words seemingly by appearance.

They can pronounce individual letters and also write the letters when hearing their names; for example, if I tell them to write "jii", they will write "j" as instructed (though sometimes as a mirror image).

When do children typically progress to actually reading words and what would be a good next step on the way there?

The child and the language are Finnish.